# Is this formula an atomic formula?

Tags: first-order-logic

For example, the formula $\forall x.\;P(x)\wedge∃y.\;Q(y,f(x))\vee∃z.\;R(z)$ contains the atoms

$$P(x),\;Q(y,f(x)),\;R(z) $$

I'm reading definition from wikipedia but I'm somehow confused  if this whole statement is atomic formula

Comment: No. A formula like $\alpha \land \beta$ is not *atomic*.

Comment: An atomic formula is a single predicate $P(x)$ or an equality $x=y$. See [First order logic : formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Formulas).

Comment: Use LaTeX please.

Answer (score 0):

No. By definition, a formula is atomic if it is

- of the form $P(t_1, \ldots t_n)$, for an $n$-aray predicate $P$ and terms $t_1, \ldots t_n$, or
- of the form $t_1 = t_2$, for two terms $t_1, t_2$.

So an atomic formula is a simple predication or equality (assuming that your logic has the equality sign $=$).
Anything that has a connective or a quantifier in it is *not* an atomic formula.

Since $∀x. P (x) ∧ ∃y. Q (y, f (x)) ∨ ∃z. R (z)$ involves logical connectives ($\land, \lor$) as well as quantifiers ($\forall, \exists, \exists$), it is not atomic.

A formula that is not atomic is sometimes called *complex*.